# how to keep passwords out of terraform code file

Tags: azure, terraform

I am creating an azure sql server in azure:

I have a `variables.tf` file which currently has the admin password:

```
variable "sql_server_admin_password" {
  description = "admin password"
  default = "xxxx"  
}
```

I then reference that in the main file:

```
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "main" {
  name                         = var.sql_server_name
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = var.sql_server_admin_login
  administrator_login_password = var.sql_server_admin_password
}
```

I don't want to check this file into source control.

Is there a terraform way of getting the admin user name and password into environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your deployment is setup. You can generate a password (random_password) and store it securely in a keyvault and reference it further on when deploying your SQL. You can also reference an existing keyvault secret to be your password.

Some links related to this from Terraform:

*Creation of key vault in Terraform: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/key_vault.html*

*Fetch the secret from an existing Azure Key Vault:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/key_vault_secret.html*

Information related to Azure Key Vault can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/

Comment: Thank you .  Do you know of any links of how to setup terraform in production in azure.  At the moment I am running the scripts from my laptop

Comment: This shows a way to incorporate it into an Azure DevOps pipeline: https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/terraform/

Answer (score 1):

As the simplest option, you can remove the default value of the variable and pass the variable when execute `terraform plan` or `apply`. Just `export TF_SQL_SERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD=<password>` and run terraform commands. Also, it could be securely passed during builds. Integrating Azure KeyVault or HashiCorp Vault to retrieve the variables are a more complex, but more secure way to this.